# how to define a new colorbox command or environment like this?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to DIY a environment like the tcolorbox stye:

[image]

and I read the docs of tcolorbox and find this:

```
    \begin{docTcbKey}[][doc new=2014-11-28]{no recording}{}{}
  Disables \refCom{tcbrecord} and \refKey{/tcb/record} inside the current
  group.
\end{docTcbKey}
```

and the `docTcbkey` is define as `\tcbmakedocSubKey{docTcbKey}{tcb}`

but the `doctcbkey` is write latex3:

```
    \NewDocumentCommand \tcbmakedocSubKey { m m }
  {
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{ O{} +O{} m m +m }
      {
        \__tcobox_doc_entry_begin:nnn
          {
            doc@sub@keypath=#2,
            doc~keypath=##1,
            doc~name={##3},
            doc~parameter={##4},
            doc~description={##5},
            ##2
          }
          {}{key}
      }
      {
        \__tcobox_doc_entry_end:n { key }
      }
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1*}{}
      {
        \group_begin:
        \tcb@doc@toindexfalse
        \begin{#1}
      }
      {
        \end{#1}
        \group_end:
      }
  }
```

it is complex, it is more easy to design a new tcolorbox environment
and  I want to make a key like this:
[image]

1. first replace `/tcb` with`tcb`
   2.then the delimiter `/` with `_`
2. then last number `123`` can be changed to any number that can be filled
3. the right side is with other text
4. here is the template :
   change the `/tcb/vig/south` to `SYS_VIG_123`

Answer (score 1):

The simple one!

```
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!10}

\colorbox{blue!10}{Put your text}
```

Comment: Well sure, you can use a butter knife to cut down a tree, buck up into rounds and then split them into firewood, sure...

Comment: Would you share us the best way? So, that we can learn. Actually, I've difficulties to use `\linenumbers`,  along with  `\colorlet{shadecolor}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mykey}[3][]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!30, 
    boxrule=0pt, attach title to upper={\hfill},
    fonttitle=\ttfamily, coltitle=purple,title=#2,#1]#3\end{tcolorbox}}
    
\begin{document}
\mykey{Some text}{More text}

\mykey[colback=cyan!30, coltitle=blue!70!black]{Some text}{More text}
\end{document}
```

[image]